# Is there a more efficient way to check for a specific string format such as post code?

Tags: python, string

I am a Python newbie and wondered if someone could help with a way to check the format of a string, for example a postcode, with letters and numbers at specific points.

E.g. `LLNNLL`

---

Using the help I have received I have put this together which seems to work, but I am wondering if there is a easier or more efficient way to do this.

```
import re

#enters and saves the input
postcode=input("Enter the postcode")

#uses the re command to set the format to check
pccheck=re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}')

#checks if postcode matches the pattern
matching=pccheck.match(postcode)

#does this if the postcode does not match the format
if str(matching) =="None":
    print("The postcode is irregular")
    file=open("wrongcodes.txt","a")
    file.write(str(postcode)+"\n")
    file.close()

#does this if it does match
else:
    print("The postcode is ok")
```

Comment: The `re` module would be well suited to this, but you'll garner significantly better responses here on StackOverflow if you show us some of the code you've written that attempted to solve the problem you're facing.  This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment above mentioned you need the `re` module.

```
import re

post_code = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}')

matching = post_code.match('AB12CD') # this is true
another_matching = post_code.match('1AB3BC') # this is false
```

`[a-zA-Z]` is for letters, `\d` is shortcut for digits (`[0-9]`), and `{2}` means exactly two characters long.

I hope this helps you. For more information check the manual on regular expressions.

Comment: i believe \w is alphanumeric so it will also match 0-9

Comment: yes, you're right, I'll fix that. I was typing to fast without thinking to much. Thanks!